# How to program Space Shuttle system

Tags: space

My question is very different but I want to learn.

What does program use for Space Shuttle programming by engineers ?

Comment: Then you should think about the hardware, not the programming language. I think the interesting part is the architecture of the hardware, which subsystems exists, which tasks can they perform, which recovery subsystems exists when main components fail. But I suppose this architecture is confidential.The programming language for writing the software for these systems is not the key. Maybe it's C/C++, maybe it's Java or in some parts Assembler.

Comment: I would be interested to know what have you found so far? How are you thinking to proceed .. at-least share some thoughts on the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAL/S (High-order Assembly Language/Shuttle)